# how to calculate negation of any number without use of negation sign program in c?

Tags: c

I tried remainder method for implementing negation which stored in array further use it but it is long procedure .If there is any another way to implement or any other trick.

Comment: Your question is like asking "Hey can I write my name without using the letters in my name?". It looks silly unless you tell us why and where.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you do this? What's the point?

If you can assume the machine uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) then you can of course apply it manually. The algorithm is ... pretty simple:

- Invert all bits
- Add one

So:

```
int negate(int x)
{
  return ~x + 1;
}
```

Of course, if you want to be really obscure you can do the bit-inversion with XOR, and hardcode for a particular integer size:

```
int negate2(int x)
{
  return (x ^ 0xffffffff) + 1;
}
```

I guess using tilde to calculate a portable XOR constant is okay too, but silly:

```
int negate3(int x)
{
  return (x ^ ~0) + 1;
}
```

Comment: i just asked without using negation

Comment: @user3098223 `~`!=`!`.

Comment: @user3098223 Uh yes, that's a tilde **~**, the operator that inverts all bits in a number. It's not the same as unary negation, at all.

Comment: one thing also sir why we use different different endianness (big endian and little endian) system to system . it not possible that it is same for all system either all big endian or all  little endian.

Comment: @user3098223 Please don't ask new questions in comments, that's not what the comments are for.

Comment: @user3098223 Well maybe first you should make it clear in what environmnent and why you need to be able to do this.

Comment: any other trick apart form tilde ???

Comment: today i just think about this thing that i am very confusing in this endiannes that why i raise this question